# force div to surround another div

Tags: html, css

At the moment I have a parent div containing 2 div's, both div's have their own border. What I try to do is to have 1 div in the left top corner and the other div surround it on the right and bottom with margin between them. Just like the image below:

[image]

Is this even possible, using css3 and html5?

Edit: Here is the layout of the div's.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="leftdiv">
        Here is some text and an image displayed
    </div>
    <div id="rightdiv">
        <div class="profile"><h4>Some text</h4><img src="...."></div>
        <div class="profile"><h4>Some text</h4><img src="...."></div>
        <div class="profile"><h4>Some text</h4><img src="...."></div>
        <div class="profile"><h4>Some text</h4><img src="...."></div>
        <div class="profile"><h4>Some text</h4><img src="...."></div>
        ..............
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your markup please

Comment: please create fiddle for this.

Comment: No, this cannot be done with pure CSS unless you introduce a lot of obsolete elements to do so. You can fake this with background images.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to fake this effect with pseudo-elements for the top-left container.

```
.first {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 30px; 
    width: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.first:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: -5px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.first:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -1px;
    height: 3px;
    width: 35px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.second {
    height: 80px; 
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

See this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/fqsDp/2/

Comment: While a valiant attempt, the 'sample' image contains a lot of rounded corners that you just won't be able to get in there, or pointing the right way, with this approach. +1 for the effort though.

Comment: Still, it is an awesome effort!

Answer (score 0):

I have the following in jsfiddle.com:

```
#main {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}

#leftdiv {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0;
    background: green;
    color: black;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(219,219,219,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(219,219,219,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dbdbdb',GradientType=0 );
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#rightdiv {
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(219,219,219,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(219,219,219,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dbdbdb',GradientType=0 );
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5unJw/